# Restaurant Menu

Tags: html, css

I want create a Restaurant style menu with menu item left aligned and price right aligned. 
I have posted my HTML and CSS. Can someone help me how to achieve this?

HTML as below:

salad £4.50

(with goat cheese)

```
<dt>Risotto £5</dt>
<dd>with celery and parmesan</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS as below:

```
.rm-content dl{
    margin: 0;
}

.rm-content dl dt,
.rm-content dl dd{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

.rm-content dl dt {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #C99944;
}

.rm-content dl dd {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0 5px 15px;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: #C99944;
}

Thank You
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that will do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/zajgvty3/1/

Basically the `dt` has two elements (classes `title` & `price`) where they both `float`.

```
.rm-content dl{
    margin: 0;
}

.rm-content dl dt,
.rm-content dl dd{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

.rm-content dl dt {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #C99944;
    clear:both;
}

.rm-content dl dt div.title{
    float:left
}

.rm-content dl dt div.price{
    float:right;
}

.rm-content dl dd {
    clear:both;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0 5px 15px;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: #C99944;
}
```

Sample Html

```
<div class="rm-content">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <div class="title">
            Risotto 
            </div>
            <div class="price">
            £5
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd>with celery and parmesan</dd>
    </dl>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple http://jsfiddle.net/5ms9h0zp/

**CSS**

```
.rm-content {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #C99944;
}
.rm-content i {
    display:block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0 5px 15px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-style:normal;
}
.rm-content em{
    float:right;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="rm-content">
    Risotto <em>£5</em> <i>with celery and parmesan</i>
    Salad <em>£4.50</em> <i>with celery and parmesan</i>
</div>
```